# Excel count Filter Rows

Tags: excel

In excel i have filtered my spreadsheet to my desired results. Now i want to count a certain column for a total number. I can't just look at the last column entry number because since its filtered the line number jumps. Is there any way to select what i want the text i want to total up and display how many rows there are. Something like

```
=SUM(select rows),
```

but sum doesn't work for this case because i'm dealing with text, and i want the total number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a countif is what you are looking for. Check out this [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) for more information and examples.

> Use COUNTIF, one of the statistical functions, to count the number of cells that meet a criterion; for example, to count the number of times a particular city appears in a customer list.